# ODE with change of variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve 
$$y'=\frac{x+y}{y}.$$
I then tried the change of variable
$$ v=\frac{y}{x},$$
and -I think-
$$y'=xu'+u$$
I went on few lines but then I got struck since the thing was clearly not going in the direction of the solution. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

The equation is

$$\frac{uu'}{1+u-u^2}=\frac{1}{x}$$

observe that

$$\frac{u}{u^2-u-1}=\frac{a}{(u-u_1)}+\frac{b}{(u-u_2)}$$

with $u_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ 
$$u_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$b=\frac{-u_2}{u_1-u_2}=\frac{u_2}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$a=\frac{-u_1}{\sqrt{5}}$$

After integration, we get

$$(u-u_1)^a(u-u_2)^b=\frac{\lambda}{x}$$
solve for $u$.

Comment: Yes I did that and used it for integrating but the result should be $x/2 +y-C/x=0$ and I can't see how to obtain it from the setup above

Comment: @Dac0 What did you find for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I found 1/2 for both, is it right?

Comment: @Dac0 I think you made a mistake. $a$ is not $1/2$

Comment: ok thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

With your Substitution we get
$$u+u'x=1+\frac{1}{u}$$ this is $$xu'=\frac{1+u-u^2}{u}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I already was at that line... I got stuck after the separation of variable...